# Is it possible to pass variables through one ActivityView/Classes to another

Tags: android, kotlin

In the MainActivity view I generate some content, id est: a list of strings, that I want to pass them to the, as an example, DetailActivity view, so this way I don't repeat part of some code.
Is there a way to do that?

Sorry if the question is vague for now, but I can improve it while I'll go reading the responses from you. Thanks for now.

Comment: Do you mean navigation args?

Comment: [It's explained in the Activity documentation.](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles) But a more typical app strucure would be a single Activity with multiple Fragments and they could share a ViewModel.